# I volume a directory in CouchDB, have error when I run `composer network start` at second time

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I add the following two lines in the CouchDB container of docker-compose file.

```
volumes:
   - ./couchdb:/opt/couchdb/data
```

My steps as follows:

1. ./startFabric.sh
2. composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1  -a
       tutorial-network.bna
3. composer network start -n tutorial-network -A
       admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V 0.0.2-deploy.10 -f
       admin@tutorial-network.card

It's ok ,and some data will store my couchdb directory.
Then I stop&remove all container:

- ./stopFabrics.sh
- ./startFabrics.sh
- composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1  -a
      tutorial-network.bna
- composer network start -n tutorial-network -A
      admin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V 0.0.2-deploy.10 -f
      admin@tutorial-network.card
  Got error as follows:

> ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid
>   responses from any peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an
>   error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:
>   chaincode exists tutorial-network) Command failed

Only when I delete the couchdb directory can it works.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  The steps you are taking above basically try to recreate the composer network.  When you persist your CouchDB volume, you are saving the state and when you try to install and start the composer network the second time it access the state and sees that the chaincode has already been installed and instantiated so it fails

Comment: @GariSingh If I want use the data in the couchdb container at an other machine or recreate the network ? who can I do?