# How to persist CouchDB data?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I created the composer network, and persist my CouchDB volume.

How can I recreate a network using the persistent couchDB data previous?

Related to this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166374/i-volume-a-directory-in-couchdb-have-error-when-i-run-composer-network-start)

Answer (score 0):

Its actually question related to docker. You need to create a docker volume and use only that volume for your container. You can backup that volume and whenever you want to start new container you can mount that volume to docker container while starting it. You can go through the docker link for [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume)

Comment: In fact , I haved volumed to docker container.
The problem is when I can't  recreate a network using the data volumed previously.

Comment: I just went through your other thread. Can you try using separate volumes for peers as well, as couch db state is generated by reading all the blocks in the peers. Make sure you give the credentials of old peers in the new peers as blocks will be readable only when you provide credentials of old peers( or maybe the new certificates should be from the same CA , you need to check these options). And you better try it without composer at first , because anyways when you setup the blockchain network, you do install a basic chaincode. If anything goes wrong some extra effort will be saved.

Comment: I have used the same CA(not regenerate).anything else needed?

Comment: For couch db there is no use of CA. CA role comes in play for peers. Peers just simply use couchdb for storing state and they access it by simply using username and password. So ideally it should be peers whose volume should be created as with that you can generate state in couchdb.

Comment: so ,can my needs be realized?

Comment: Ideally it should be.. But make sure you use same credentials for new peers as old one because I am not sure whether new credentials with same CA will work or not (Ideally it should). And dont forget to update the correct way here once its done :)